# Efficient way of computing slopes of edge lines

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, edge-detection, derivative, corner-detection

I performed edge detection on images (with Python 2-7 and OpenCV 3.2) and have results like the following picture, i.e. one-pixel-wide edges not necessarily closed (can have "loose ends"), and with possible holes :

[image]

Now I would like to get the "derivative" of these edges, meaning the "slope" at each point, as in the following image :

[image]

For the moment, the only way I managed to do it is very locally. For each point of the edge (in red in next "zoomed" picture), I create a circle around it (in pink), mask the circle with the edge to get the red point's neighbors, then compute the slope of these two neighbors.

[image]

However, it can be quite messy if edges have holes (which they often do) or are close to other edges (which they often are) and masking all the points is pretty computationally intensive, so I wonder if there is a better way.

My first idea was spline interpolation, but you need to give as input an **ordered** list of points, which you can't have for a given edge unless you use a pixel neighbor tracking algorithm which can also get quite messy in case of not-that-good edges.
I also thought of findContours but it needs closed edges or else it yields the contour of a one-pixel-wide edge, i.e. two lines on both side of the edges, started at an arbitrary location on the edge, in short it's a mess.

Is there a cleaner and more efficient way than my actual method to achieve what I want ? Does OpenCV have any resources or is its job done after edge detection (I think the latter is more probable !) ?

P.S. : "I don't think there is a better way" is an answer I'm ready to accept !

Comment: easiest would be to represent your objects as contours, but as you said your objects might have holes and and might be very difficult to represent it as a "connected" contour.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Even without holes, my objects are not necessarily closed, they are mostly loose edges. And findContours() is therefore not a help. I edited my question to take this into account.

Comment: you could still represent your curve segments by a "contour" (ordered list of point positions along the curve) but you would have to compute them differently (not findContours). after that computing the slope becomes simple and maybe in total more efficient. But still there is the problem of grouping the edges to curve segments...

Comment: Yes, and for this "grouping the edges to curve" step, I can't think of anything else than a low level algorithm where you count the number of neighbors for each pixels in order to find an extremity, then iteratively find the following neighbor... an algorithm which may not be that computationally efficient and is error-prone when connectivity is a bit tough

Comment: What do you mean by this? "Now I would like to get the "derivative" of these edges, meaning the "slope" at each point, as in the following image". The slope at each point?

 At most there is a slope for each "segment" of line.

Comment: I mean as if my edges were functions plotted in a cartesian (O,x,y) space.
Consider the case where I would have only one edge, with no holes. Then I would like to have the local slope's value for each point. Exactly like when you have f(x)=x**2, and you want to compute f ' (0), f ' (1), etc.

Comment: A slope can be thought of as the inclination of a straight line, there is no sense in talking about the slope of a curve (Only the slope of a "line" tangent to a curve). Since there are curves in your contours, you probably want to divide each contour into "straight" segments each one with a slope that defines it. Is that it?

Comment: OK, I get what you're saying. My question title might not be very well-phrased, but in the question body, there is no confusion : I want the derivative of the curve, computed locally for each point, i.e. the slope of the tangents to the curve at each point.

I guess you can say I want to " divide each contour into "straight" segments each one with a slope that defines it", but with very small "straight segments" ? Exactly like you can approximate f(x)=x**2 by straight segments and compute the slope of those to get your derivative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understood everything correctly, what you need is an ordered list of your points free from holes, because after that it seems you know how to proceed to obtain your result. **So, you should concentrate in getting an ordered gapless list.**

FindContours does output an ordered list, but probably not in the order you need. It groups connected pixels with a TOP-DOWN / LEFT-RIGHT priority. So, it swipes each row sequentially, when it hits a white pixel, it finds the first contour. So, in your image, the first contour it finds is actually the one on the right, since it has the closest to 0 Y value.

In the case of this particular image, **if you rotate it 90 degrees you'll realize that it will actually order your contours and points in the way you need**. But will this always be the case? Only you can tell. If there is a pre-process method to apply to your images that will guarantee that findContours will order your pixels in the correct way, the rest will be easy. If not, I suggest you create your own pixel-connectivity algorithm that will work as you need it to, since all your problems depends on getting an ordered list.

**Once you have the ordered list, just interpolate the missing pixels.**

If you have an ordered set of pixels, "closing the gaps" is easy, since you just need to find the gaps and interpolate between them as an approximation that probably wont hurt your algorithm.

Comment: I think you're right, though as I said in my (edited) question, findContour on a 1-pixel-wide non-closed line is really ugly. And my images will not always be this way... But I get a better sense of what the problem is now, and what I can and can't do !

Comment: Good. 

As a side note, I used findContours to describe 1-pixel-wide lines and didn't face any issue, I'm actually using it to calculate the dimensions of objects. So I don't know what may be the issue there. 

Glad I could help, cheers.